# Laravel: Posting information with a form

Tags: php, laravel

I have something like this in my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{url('/member/createMember')}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="invitation" value="{{ $invitation }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="partner" value="{{ $partner }}">
```

I would like to have `$inviation`, and `$partner` available to the `/member/createMember` function in the called controller.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this other than hidden input elements? Isn't the content of the hidden fields communicated to the end user's browser anyway? Ideally I would like avoid involving the user's browser in this. Should I just retain the `$partner` and `$invitation` in the session?

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to see it store it in the session. Otherwise hidden input fields or putting it in the URL should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options:
Hidden Fields (what I personally use for things like this)
Session Storage (this might be a bit difficult, since you can set them (by echoing JS) but it is very hard to view them (unless JS does it))

Honestly, I can't think of much else, sorry about that! The user's browser really does need to be involved, since HTTP is stateless.